# Can we check if a session value is changed in asp.net ? Is there a property like dirty flag to set?

Tags: session

I have a Session["Variable"] which is set to value1 onload.

Now depending on user action on the application , I may set Session["Variable"] = value2.

After I change the session value , Is there any property to check if Session["Variable"] is changed ?

In Short:

Onload  Session["Variable"] = value1;

SomeUserAction Session["Variable"] = value2;

Onsubmit  check if(Session["Variable"] has changed from value1)?

Is there any property for session to track the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Session_ID` that's kept by the server. The only way to *really* check if the user is the same user is to take that Session_ID with other verifiable information and [hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) them together with a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) that only you know. Then pass that forward as a variable. If the hash on the next page fails then the session was hijacked or altered.

```
string matchhash = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(session&salt, "sha1");
```

If this is for a super high security project, you'll want to look at this post since it is possible, but not probably that someone could crack your [Hash and SSL exchanges using an array of Playstations](http://hackaday.com/2008/12/30/25c3-hackers-completely-break-ssl-using-200-ps3s/).